# How to evalute this correct in bash script?

Tags: bash, acl, synology

On my Synology I try to perform a check in a script.
Script is exectuted as root. For permission-check below I have to use sudo.

I invoke following code in my shell script:

```
CMD="sudo -u USERNAME synoacltool -check '/SOMEPATH/' rwxpdDaARWcCo"
CHK=$($CMD)
echo "Result: $CHK"
```

But the output of the script shows the --help of synoacltool:
    Result: Usage: synoacltool

```
SYNOPSIS ...blablabla...
```

Running the same command directly on bash prompt is as expected:

```
Permission [rwxpdDaARWcCo]: [Deny]
```

I did some search but didn't found my solution.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Does "running the same command" include the "sudo -u USERNAME" part?

Comment: Yes. sudo -u USERNAME synoacltool -check '/SOMEPATH/' rwxpdDaARWcCo

Comment: I found, that the command only fails to --help, when SOMEPATH has a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should'n put commands with special symbols like ' or " in vars. That doesn't work. Try this.

```
CHK=$(sudo -u USERNAME synoacltool -check "/SOMEPATH/" rwxpdDaARWcCo)
echo "Result: $CHK"
```